# Why the modal is empty and the selectedItem is null in my BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to BootstrapVue, not sure if what I'm doing is right. I'm using BootstrapVue to create an editable table with quantity input, when clicking the table row, it will show the item image modal.
(used `<%%>` instead of `{{}}` because of the jinja2 crush)

By my code below, the modal didn't show anything, `selectedItem` is null.

Empty modal

[image: 1]

My template:

```
<b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" @row-clicked="showImage" responsive striped hover>
    <template #cell(quantity)="data">
        <b-form-input type="number" :value="data.value" v-model="data.item.quantity" max="9999"
                                      min="0"></b-form-input>
    </template>
    <template #cell(total)="data">
        <% getItemTotal(data.item) %>
    </template>

    <template slot="bottom-row" slot-scope="data">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><% countTotal %></td>
    </template>
</b-table>

<b-modal v-model="showModal" @hidden="resetModal">
    <img v-if="selectedItem && selectedItem.image" :src="selectedItem.image" alt="Selected Item"
                         class="img-fluid">
</b-modal>
```

My script:

```
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
            items: {{  }},
            fields: [
                {key: 'category', label: 'Category'},
                {key: 'description', label: 'Description'},
                {key: 'price', label: 'Price (USD)'},
                {key: 'discount', label: 'Discount'},
                {key: 'quantity', label: 'Quantity'},
                {key: 'total', label: 'Total'},
                {key: 'image', label: 'Image'},
            ],
            showModal: false,
            selectedItem: null,
        },
   methods: {
            showImage(event) {
                this.selectedItem = event.item
                this.showModal = true
            },
            resetModal() {
                this.selectedItem = null
            }
        },
    delimiters: ['<%', '%>'],
    })
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try to console the `event` inside `showImage` function?

Comment: yes tried, the event is there, can see the image key and value

Comment: what is inside the `items: {{}}`? Can you provide the real data?

Comment: items: {{ distributorProductsFormatted|safe }}, it is a python function in another file I used to pass the data in. The data structure is exactly same as the fields show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing from

```
this.selectedItem = event.item
```

to

```
this.selectedItem = event
```

I consoled `event.item`showing it is not defined. It turned out that event can be the selectedItem.